# How should I use MongoDB GridFS to store my big-size data?

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

After I read MongoDB Gridfs official document , I know that GridFS is used by MongoDB to store large file(size>16M),the  file can be a video , a movie or anything else.But now , what I meet , is large strutured data , not a simple physical file. Size of the data  exceeds the limit. To make it more detailed, what I am dealing with is thousands of gene sequences,and  many of them  exceeds BSON-document size limit .You can just consider each gene sequence as a simple string ,and the string is so large that some string has exceeds the mongoDB BSOM size limit.So ,what can I do to solve such a problem ? Is GridFS still suitable to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

GridFS will split up the data in *chunks* of smaller size, that's how it overcomes the size limit. It's particularly useful for streaming data, because you can quickly access data at any given offset since the chunks are indexed.

Storing 'structured' data in the tens of megabytes sounds a bit weird: either you need to access parts of the data based on some criteria, then you need a different data structure that allows access to smaller parts of the data.

Or you really need to process the entire data set based on some criteria. In that case, you'll want an efficiently indexed collection that you can query based on your criteria and that contains the id of the file that must then be processed.

Without a concrete example of the problem, i.e. what does the query and the data structure look like, it will be hard to give you a more detailed answer.

Comment: Hi , I have a more detailed solution ,can you help me to check if it is reasonable?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757575/how-should-i-design-my-data-storage-scheme-using-mongodb